# Power multiple 5V/12V devices off a single transformer?

Tags: hardware

I have these devices in my cabinet (Q-Panel) that have these power requirements:

1. 21V 1.2Amp
2. 5V 500mA
3. 12V 1.5A
4. 12V 1.5A
5. 48V 1.25A

Obviously I can't do much about #1 and #5. I want to be able to have a single transformer/adapter and power #2, #3 and #4 off from it.

Is there anything that is a single transformer/adapter that allows you to pull multiple lines from - ideally that can be switched to 5V or 12V so that I can power all 3 devices from the same block instead of having 3 warts in my cabinet I could just have one?

EDIT: #5 is a POE injector. Can I just pull a cable off from this and use the power wires and just splice it into the plug? It says 48V - will the device automatically step this down, or does that only work for POE specific devices?

Answer (score 1):

A standard PC power supply gives out these voltages (3v,5v,12v).

Check the amperage, and make sure it can support 3.5A or more, then it will be fine.

As for (1) and (5), they are a bit more specific.

You may have to break out the soldering iron, but it will work!

Comment: Do I just find the right wires that supply the correct voltage and then splice them into the cord that plugs into the device? Do I need to worry about amperage of the device I am powering vs the amperage of what is being put out by the power supply?

Comment: just use a multimeter to check the voltages. Usually the standard is red 5v yellow 12v. the wikipedia article is nice. as I mentioned, the amps should be above or equal to the demand. If your power supply is 4A but you only draw 500mA, you are below the threshold so it is fine.